# Is it possible to automatically schedule old Tumblr posts to appear on Twitter?

Tags: twitter, tumblr, automation

I've got a large Tumblr archive and would like to tweet one post every few days to Twitter. Is there any way of doing this automatically?

Comment: You can easily do that with a script that interacts with Twitter's REST API.